# git filter-branch failing while trying to split repo

Tags: git

I'm trying to split a big git blob into separate git repos (while preserving history).  It appears to be working up until this error.  When I look in the folder I have 2584 new files (that used to be under source control)

```
git filter-branch -d /tmp/readers --subdirectory-filter indexlibs/readers/ -- master
Rewrite 4962c5e30b4a59d48a2d5b6e6e49cc1c13068127 (99/99)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
error: Untracked working tree file 'somefile.sh' would be overwritten by merge.
```

There is only one commit log message for `somefile.sh`, the initial add.

How do I work around this error?

Comment: Seems like your branch was successfully rewritten anyway. Try `git checkout -f master` (or delete the file manually and then checkout the branch)